# jenkins artifactory JellyTagException

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, devops

I have the newest Jenkins LTS version: 2.138.2.

Everytime, after installation of Artifactory Plugin, when I enter `"Manage Jenkins -> Configure System"` I get the Exception:

```
Stack-Trace: 

org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins    
/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.149.jar!/jenkins/model/Jenkins/configure.jelly:51:84: <st:include> No page found 'config.jelly' for class org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.GlobalConfigFiles
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:124)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
```

I have search already long in Interent. I have tried the newest `Jenkins Version: 2.149`

Maybe should I report a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred to me also this morning when I updated the [config-file-provider](https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/config-file-provider) plugin from v3.3 to v3.4.  I raised this [ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54411) against the plugin.

You will still be able to navigate to the Manage Plugins > Installed tab and downgrade this plugin to the version you previously had installed.

I resolved this issue for myself by downgrading back to v3.3.